# Is there any command equivalent to the itshape of the CJK main font?

Tags: fonts, cjk, xecjk

As you see, the codes

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[ItalicFont={it.otf}, BoldFont={bf.otf}]{rm.otf}
```

set the `\rmfamilly` of the CJK main font, the `\itshape` of the CJK main font and the `\bfseries` of the CJK main font. My question is

> **is there any command equivalent to the `\itshape` of the CJK main font? Or could we define such command?**

`\itshape` clearly effects both English and CJK characters, while I hope such command to effect CJK characters only but not to effect English characters. By the way, I don't want to define a font command which invoking directly the font adopted in the `\itshape` of the CJK main font such as:

```
\newCJKfontfamily[yuanziti]\ziti{it.otf}
```

or

```
\setCJKfamilyfont{yuanziti}{it.otf}
\newcommand*{\ziti}{\CJKfamily{yuanziti}}
```

since when I changed the `\itshape` of the CJK main font I have to redefine `\ziti` again.

Comment: Why you need to change the `\ifshape / ItalicFont` of the CJK main font at the middle of document? There may be better way to achieve that.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I want the CJK characters to be itshape whitle the English characters not to change.

Comment: If italic English is not desired, why not just say `\setmainfont{eng-rm.otf}[ItalicFont=eng-rm.otf]`. It’s a hack for sure, but it works.

Comment: @RuixiZhang I need a command to make **Chinese characters in a local area** become the `\itshape` of CJK main font while **English characters in a local area** still the `\rmfamily` of (en) main font since the appearance of mixing upshape Chinese characters (itshape Chinese characters are usually indeed not slanted) with itshape English characters (indeed slanted) are strange.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `xeCJK` only provides a family switching mechanism for CJK fonts, which includes macros like `\CJK@family`, `\CJKdefaultfamily`, `\xeCJK_switch_family:` and many initial settings. What OP wanted is a similar mechanism for shape switching.

Try the example below as a *very beginning and fragile attempt*, not a real or mature solution.

```tex
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctex}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \CJK@shape { \f@shape }

% patch xeCJK
\cs_set:Npn \__xeCJK_font_csname:n #1
  { xeCJK/#1/\f@series/\CJK@shape/\f@size }

\tl_set:No \l_xeCJK_current_font_tl
  { \__xeCJK_font_csname:n { \CJK@family } }

\tl_set:No \l_xeCJK_current_punct_font_tl
  { \__xeCJK_font_csname:n { \CJK@punctfamily } }

\AddToHook{normalfont}
  { \cs_set:Npn \CJK@shape { \f@shape } }

% new user commands
\cs_new:Npn \CJKitshape
  { \cs_set:Npn \CJK@shape { \itdefault } }

\cs_new:Npn \CJKupshape
  { \cs_set:Npn \CJK@shape { \updefault } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% helper
\newcommand\test{%
  \makebox[10em][l]{%
    \expanded{{\noexpand\normalfont CJK \CJK@shape\space + En \f@shape}}}%
  \rmfamily 中文abc \heiti 中文abc\par}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
            \test
\itshape    \test
\upshape    \test

\bigskip

            \test
\CJKitshape \test
\CJKupshape \test
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your attempt!